# Conservation of mass and nuclear decay

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, mass-energy

I was doing this question:

> Reactions of radioactive decay, as mentioned in the text, do not obey Lavoisier's law (conservation of mass), once there is no conservation of mass in the process, but rather energy.

The answer says the item is True, but i think it's false.

The text mentions this decay:

$$\rm
^{60}Co \to {}^{60}Ni + \beta + γ
$$

Here are my questions:

1. Since mass is energy, there's no conservation, right?
2. The Law of conservation of mass by Lavoisier is wrong? Since there's a slightly change in the mass of the final product.
3. Using the equation $E= mc^2$, do i have to use the momentum in this case?
4. I'm very confused by this also: If the number of protons in the 60Co was 27, and after the decay is 28 (60Ni), does the electron emitted in the decay make the 28 protons of 60Ni 27 protons? So the charge in the end is the same? How is this possible? I'm confused: the energy is conserved? The mass is conserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Total energy is conserved, not total mass.
2. Yes, mass is not conserved exactly.
3. The correct equation would be $E = \sqrt{m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2}$. For example the photon ($\gamma$) has energy $E = pc$ since it is massless.
4. Charge is conserved, yes. One of the neutrons is converted into a proton and releases an electron (and a anti-electron neutrino), see the [Beta Decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) Wikipedia article. Thus the overall charge is the same.

Comment: 1.But in the process, there's some energy that is not conserved?

Comment: No energy is absolutely conserved. If the Co atom is initially at rest, in the final state all three resulting particles are moving away from each ither. In such a way that the total (relativistic) energy is conserved and overall momentum is conserved

Comment: What a blur of the eyes.   Deacy  4H -> 3H + n ; m > 0, p = 0;

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the already given answers, I want to point out that although if you add up the rest masses of the decay results you will get a total slightly *smaller* than the rest mass of the original atom, so in that sense mass is not conserved, there is actually a sense in which mass **is** conserved. This sense is explained in the [Invariant Mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) Wikipedia article. Quoting from it:

> If objects within a system are in relative motion [as is the case of the decay results], then the invariant mass of the whole system will differ from the sum of the objects' rest masses. This is also equal to the total energy of the system divided by $c^2$. ... Since the mass of systems must be measured with a weight or mass scale in a center of momentum frame in which the entire system has zero momentum, such a scale always measures the system's invariant mass. For example, a scale would measure the kinetic energy of the molecules in a bottle of gas to be part of invariant mass of the bottle, and thus also its rest mass. The same is true for massless particles in such system, which add invariant mass and also rest mass to systems, according to their energy.

In this sense, the total *invariant mass* (a.k.a. the rest mass) is conserved in the decay, just like energy and momentum is conserved (the invariant mass is just a function of both). However, you just need to remember that the total invariant mass after the decay doesn't mean simply adding up the invariant mass of the individual resulting particles.

Quoting from another Wikipedia article, on [Mass in special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity),

> ... the invariant mass of an isolated system (i.e., one closed to both mass and energy) ... is a constant, conserved quantity for isolated systems and single observers, even during chemical and nuclear reactions. The concept of invariant mass is widely used in particle physics, because the invariant mass of a particle's decay products is equal to its rest mass. This is used to make measurements of the mass of particles like the Z boson or the top quark.

Comment: Is it a hypothetical example to illustrate the concept of invariant mass? It isn't saying that a scale can actually measure the kinetic energy of the gas molecules in reality but that if there was a scale that could measure the mass of the system in a center of momentum frame, where the total momentum of the system is zero, then it would also measure the kinetic energy of the gas molecules as part of the invariant mass of the bottle? However, such a scale does not exist in reality, and a normal scale can only measure the weight of the bottle, which isn't the same as its mass or invariant mass?

Comment: It's "hypothetical" in the sense that you'd be hard-pressed to find scales with such fantastic accuracy, but in theory, it's possible. The "weight" of the object is nothing more than the force applied by gravity on the object, which is proportional to the mass, so a device measuring this force (a device for measuring "weight") will indeed measure the kinetic energy as part of the weight of the object.

Comment: In essence, are you stating that for example a closed air-filled bottle when measured on a "hypothetical super accurate scale" will measure the total mass of air+bottle + K.E. of molecules of bottle and air? But I am wondering why aren't K.E. forces balance out as molecules are exerting forces in all directions.

Comment: Momentum, a vector, "balances out" when force acts from all direction. Energy does not, it adds up. If I stand in the middle of the road and two cars come crashing into me - one from the left and one from the right - these crashes don't "balance out" and I suffer a collision with twice the energy, not zero. The momentum in this scenario does balance out to zero - In an ideal 1D setting, I'll be left in the middle of the crash site with zero momentum - i.e., squashed but with zero velocity.

Comment: I understand that much. But I don't understand how a scale that measures weight indicates the kinetic energy of the system.

Comment: Well, it's because according to general relativity, gravity acts on **energy**. Even photons (which have zero rest mass when they are alone) experience gravity. When you measure weight, you measure gravity, and any form of energy (including kinetic energy) increases this gravity.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. The Law of conservation of mass by Lavoisier is wrong? Since there's a slightly change in the mass of the final product.

Physics uses mathematical models to fit data and observations and , more important, then uses them as tools for further predictions, this is what makes the models useful.

The models depend on the framework, the dimensions in space and time, the dimensions in energy and momentum.

Broadly two categories exist: Classical physics, which are the models used to describe observations before the twentieth century, and the quantum regime, which had to be invoked to explain data in small dimensions.

In addition, there is special relativity and General relativity used when  momenta are large or gravitational masses ( as classically defined) are large.

Each mathematical model is successful in its frame of reference.

Thermodynamics was first modeled with its laws ( laws are extra axioms needed to define physical solutions for the differential equations used), and then it was discovered that it emerged from statistical mechanics in a continuous, provable manner.

Similarly classical mechanics can be shown to emerge from the underlying level of quantum mechanics, classical electrodynamics from quantum electrodynamics .

The law of conservation of mass fitted macroscopic observations until the twentieth century, when it was discovered that for large energies and momenta one had to use special relativity to describe the data, and in special relativity the only laws are conservation of energy and momentum, [in a four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) . This makes mass the "length" of the four vector, given in formula   3. in the answer of Kai.

When adding [three dimensional  vectors,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/ltrans.html) the resultant vector has the length given by the vectorial addition, not the sum of the lengths of each vector. Similarly the addition of two four vectors does not conserve the mass. The rest mass is invariant under Lorentz transformations for each object under consideration. In the framework of small dimensions and/or large energies  where special relativity has to be used mass is not conserved.

Physics frameworks can be shown in overlap regions to be mathematically consistent, within the experimental errors in each framework.

Comment: What nonsense. Models are supposed to be unified and that's it. Non-unified models are simply wrong. Mixing the theory of relativity with this topic is pure fantasy. You simply do not understand what mass is and what is the origin of these processes.